# Python Annotation in 3.9 listed as NameError

Tags: python, annotations, python-3.9

Recently I've been using leetcode to learn Python, and one of the questions has a class and a function definition as starter code like so:

```
Class Solution:
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
```

However, when I try to write my solution in my own IDE, it gives me the following error:

```
~/VSCode/Python  /usr/bin/python3.9 /home/dozydoh/VSCode/Python/test.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/dozydoh/VSCode/Python/test.py", line 1, in <module>
    class Solution:
  File "/home/dozydoh/VSCode/Python/test.py", line 2, in Solution
    def twoSum(self, nums: List[int], target: int) -> List[int]:
NameError: name 'List' is not defined
```

I upgraded to Python 3.9 but still receive the same error.  Why is the annotation being interpreted like this?  I thought it would be only used by 3rd libraries or something along those lines.

TIA

Comment: Write this at the top `from typing import List`

Answer (score 0):

You are right that it is supported, but as I wrote in my comment, you need to import this name.

You can do that via:

```py
from typing import List


# Rest of code
# ...
```

More info can be found here: https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html.

Answer (score 0):

In 3.9 you can also use types themselves in annotations. e.g: 
`def twoSum(self, nums: list[int], target: int) -> list[int]:`

This means you won't have to import List from typing

This is described in [What’s New In Python 3.9](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.9.html#type-hinting-generics-in-standard-collections)